# In this passage, what does "a pair of" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, pronouns

> “Er — Petunia, dear — you haven’t heard from your sister lately, have
>   you?”
>  As he had expected, Mrs. Dursley looked shocked and angry.
>   After all, they normally pretended she didn’t have a sister.
>   “No,” she said sharply. “Why?”
>  “Funny stuff on the news,” Mr.
>   Dursley mumbled. “Owls… shooting stars… and there were a lot of
>   funny-looking people in town today…”
>  “So?” snapped Mrs.
>   Dursley.
>  “Well, I just thought… maybe… it was something to do
>   with… you know… her crowd.”
>  Mrs. Dursley sipped her tea through
>   pursed lips. Mr. Dursley wondered whether he dared tell her he’d heard
>   the name “Potter.” He decided he didn’t dare. Instead he said, as
>   casually as he could, “Their son — he’d be about Dudley’s age now,
>   wouldn’t he?”
>  “I suppose so,” said Mrs. Dursley stiffly.
>   “What’s his name again? Howard, isn’t it?”
>  “Harry. Nasty, common
>   name, if you ask me.”
>  “Oh, yes,” said Mr. Dursley, his heart
>   sinking horribly. “Yes, I quite agree.”
>  He didn’t say another
>   word on the subject as they went upstairs to bed. While Mrs. Dursley
>   was in the bathroom, Mr. Dursley crept to the bedroom window and
>   peered down into the front garden. The cat was still there. It was
>   staring down Privet Drive as though it were waiting for
>   something.
>  Was he imagining things? Could ***all this*** have
>   anything to do with ***the Potters***? If it did… if it got out
>   that ***they*** were related to ***a pair of*** — well, he didn’t think he
>   could bear it.
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

What do the last two highlighted terms refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*They* refers to the Dursleys. I.e if it got out that the Dursleys were related to the Potters.

*A pair of—* is cut off, because Mr Dursley doesn't want to think about the thing that the Potters are. I don't know what Mr Dursley thinks the Potters are, but that is what would replace the dash. For example "a pair of wizards".

Comment: If 'a pair' is the Potters, logically, 'they' needs to be the Dursleys, doesn't they?

Comment: Yes. The *pair* referred to in "a pair of —" are Mr. and Mrs. Potter (not Harry).